# Аккордион для каждого элемента

Tags: vue.js

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на заголовок отображались не все 3 параграфа, а 1 параграф, идущий за соответствующим заголовком?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  showEl: false
  }
});
```

```css
h3 {
  margin: 10px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3 @click="showEl = !showEl">Accordion 1</h3>
  <p v-show="showEl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur provident nihil, hic voluptate ut, perspiciatis assumenda nemo autem ipsum id inventore modi quidem. Assumenda, praesentium tempora, sint voluptatem neque at?</p>
  <h3>Accordion 2</h3>
  <p v-show="showEl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus id aut, consectetur accusamus ipsam, consequuntur eius voluptatem neque sunt totam vel eligendi earum, assumenda quisquam, autem asperiores quis fugit necessitatibus.</p>
  <h3>Accordion 3</h3>
  <p v-show="showEl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dignissimos, magni sunt autem molestiae, dolorem tempore consectetur, eos quo laboriosam maiores est voluptatibus consequatur aliquid eaque error quia libero. Itaque.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой способ - это использовать переменную, которая указывает какой элемент показывать. Либо можно воспользоваться готовым компонентом из библиотеки. Например bootstrap-vue

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
     showEl: 0
  }
});
```

```css
h3 {
  margin: 10px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h3 @click="showEl = 0">Accordion 1</h3>
  <p v-show="showEl === 0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur provident nihil, hic voluptate ut, perspiciatis assumenda nemo autem ipsum id inventore modi quidem. Assumenda, praesentium tempora, sint voluptatem neque at?</p>
  <h3 @click="showEl = 1">Accordion 2</h3>
  <p v-show="showEl === 1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus id aut, consectetur accusamus ipsam, consequuntur eius voluptatem neque sunt totam vel eligendi earum, assumenda quisquam, autem asperiores quis fugit necessitatibus.</p>
  <h3 @click="showEl = 2">Accordion 3</h3>
  <p v-show="showEl === 2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt dignissimos, magni sunt autem molestiae, dolorem tempore consectetur, eos quo laboriosam maiores est voluptatibus consequatur aliquid eaque error quia libero. Itaque.</p>
</div>
```